# killall doesn't kill all and rarely kills, what is the command for then?

Tags: process, kill, killall

I occasionally use the `killall` command to kill processes. The reason why I say ocassionally is that in some cases it hasn't worked for me.

A recent example was with thunderbird where there were about 5 instances in memory so I decided to use the `killall` command. It killed 2 processes and 3 were still left in memory. Tried again and the 3 were still there.

So I manually used the `kill -9` command to kill each of the individual processes via their pids. That worked.

I mostly use the `kill -9` command as it works. The `killall` command has let me down so many times I just don't bother using it. But there must be a reason why it doesn't work. Am I using it wrong?

I know there are other commands like `pkill` but I would be grateful to understand why the `killall` command doesn't work as expected. I have even tried to kill just one process and it is a hit and miss affair. But the `kill -9` command works every time.

Any ideas?

PS: `sudo` doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From the man page for killall

> killall sends a signal to all processes running any of the specified
>   commands. If no signal name is specified, SIGTERM is sent.

When you do a `kill -9`, you are sending the SIGKILL signal. If you want to send a SIGKILL with killall, you need to do

```
killall -s SIGKILL <PROCESSNAME>
```

A good explanation of the difference between SIGKILL and SIGTERM (and why you should try SIGTERM first)

From http://rackerhacker.com/2010/03/18/sigterm-vs-sigkill/

> Sending signals to processes using kill on a Unix system is not a new
>   topic for most systems administrators, but I’ve been asked many times
>   about the difference between kill and kill -9.
>
> Anytime you use kill on a process, you’re actually sending the process
>   a signal (in almost all situations – I’ll get into that soon).
>   Standard C applications have a header file that contains the steps
>   that the process should follow if it receives a particular signal. You
>   can get an entire list of the available signals on your system by
>   checking the man page for kill.
>
> Consider a command like this:
>
> `kill 2563`
>
> This would send a signal called SIGTERM to the process. Once
>   the process receives the notice, a few different things can happen:
>
> - the process may stop immediately
> - the process may stop after a short delay after cleaning up resources
> - the process may keep running indefinitely
>
> The application can determine what it wants to do once a
>   SIGTERM is received. While most applications will clean up their
>   resources and stop, some may not. An application may be configured to
>   do something completely different when a SIGTERM is received. Also, if
>   the application is in a bad state, such as waiting for disk I/O, it
>   may not be able to act on the signal that was sent.
>
> Most system administrators will usually resort to the more abrupt
>   signal when an application doesn’t respond to a SIGTERM:
>
> `kill -9 2563`
>
> The -9 tells the kill command that you want to send
>   signal #9, which is called SIGKILL. With a name like that, it’s
>   obvious that this signal carries a little more weight.
>
> Although SIGKILL is defined in the same signal header file as SIGTERM,
>   it cannot be ignored by the process. In fact, the process isn’t even
>   made aware of the SIGKILL signal since the signal goes straight to the
>   kernel init. At that point, init will stop the process. The process
>   never gets the opportunity to catch the signal and act on it.
>
> However, the kernel may not be able to successfully kill the process
>   in some situations. If the process is waiting for network or disk I/O,
>   the kernel won’t be able to stop it. Zombie processes and processes
>   caught in an uninterruptible sleep cannot be stopped by the kernel,
>   either. A reboot is required to clear those processes from the system.

When you sent killall (SIGTERM) to the thunderbird processes, you requested those processes to stop. Some of those processes weren't working correctly (probably why you needed to kill them in the first place), so they couldn't act on the SIGTERM signal.

Comment: Any speculation on why it only killed some of the thunderbird instances?

Comment: @Doogfar See my edited writeup (or the page I linked)

Comment: Thanks, also explains why my Thunderbird corrupted, kill -9 was too harsh

Comment: Still doesn't work always.

Answer (score 6):

`killall` accepts most of the same syntax as `kill`. In particular, there's no need to write anything fancy to make `killall` do the equivalent of `kill -9`. This works just fine:

```
killall -9 thunderbird
```

(Of course, as discussed, you should usually be reluctant to use `killall -9` or, equivalently, `killall -KILL`, unless other measures have already been tried without success.)

Comment: Still doesn't work always so there must be something else.

Comment: Use:
> sudo killall -s SIGTERM

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a quick answer:

```
sudo killall -s SIGTERM processname
```

Comment: I think this is valuable, as sometimes a process can't be killed because it's owned by another user account; then running `kill` or `killall` as root with `sudo` can help. [`SIGTERM` is the default signal](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/killall.1.html#description) so this works the same without `-s SIGTERM`, but including it does no harm. Although the OP mentions that `sudo` didn't help--and one doesn't usually run Thunderbird as another user--we don't know which commands were tried with `sudo`, and people sent here (by search engines or humans) may have a different problem.