# What's the difference between kill and killall

Tags: bash

The difference between kill and killall

I tried `kill` command as

```
$ kill "PDF Expert"
-bash: kill: PDF Expert: arguments must be process or job IDs
```

It report error,
However, when test with

```
$ killall "PDF Expert"
```

The application   "PDF Expert" was closed.

What's the difference between them?

Comment: Do you think that this answer is a satisfactory explanation of the difference between `kill` and `killall`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/271028/killall-doesnt-kill-all-and-rarely-kills-what-is-the-command-for-then/271032#271032?

Comment: Is the answer not already present in the question? *arguments must be process or job IDs*

Comment: `whatis kill killall`

Comment: kill will terminate a single process, killall , as the name implies, will kill all processes of the name given. See https://linuxconfig.org/kill-vs-killall-difference-and-command-usage for details.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? `man kill` and `man killall`

Comment: [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/507051)

Answer (score 2):

`kill` works by process ID but `killall` can determine the process ID by process name. If you give the process name instead of the process ID, `killall` might find the process ID and kill it.